# can't create win32 project

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Window Desktop, can't create win32 project.

the windows that welcomes to the wizard has three empty bullets under "these are the current project settings". Both the cancel and the finish button do not work.

The folder for the application is created but no files inside.

http://m1306.hizliresim.com/1b/1/np8k5.png

Comment: Sounds like the installation of VS is borked - you might need to uninstall VS and resinstall it.

Comment: Why did you tag this C#?  Win32 is for C++.

Comment: This dialog is pretty unusual as far as dialogs go in Visual Studio, the underlying implementation is Javascript.  In other words, you are using an embedded browser, Internet Explorer, aka WebBrowser.  The diagnostic therefore is that it isn't VS that's borked on your machine, it is Internet Explorer.  If not outright broken, maybe you did something drastic to get Javascript to stop executing on your machine.  Not a good idea.